# How to set IsHitTestVisible to false when Messagebox shows in main Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, messagebox

I have a requirement that when there is a messageBox shown at top of the mainWindow in WPF the mainWindow hittest should be set to False. and by clicking on the ok of the MessageBox the ishittestVisible should be true automatically. I am pretty new to WPF but I have tried the below code. But unable to figure how do I proceed.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Style>
       <Style>
          <Setter Property="Control.IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
             <Style.Triggers>
                < />
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <local:ShareCtrl x:Name="shareCtrl" Width="700" Height="725" />        
    </Grid>
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Do I set any member value in the viewModel to false in viewmodel when MessageBox pops up. But then how do I set it to True when I click on the Ok button of the Messagebox? Please suggest and help me.

Edit:
In ViewModel I have the following code.

```
{
...
    else if(ErrorCase)
    {
       string str = "Error Message"
       ShowMessage(str);
       return;
    }
    ...
}
    private void ShowMessage(string str)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You mean when MessageBox is visible, the user may not click on window in the background? Well, that is already the case. You dont need to do anything there. :)

Comment: Yes that suppose to be the case but in may case, user is suppose hit enter Key,  then the MessageBox OK button gets hit, MesaageBox disappears then again the main textbox gets hit as becasue the evet gets ruted I think, and again MessageBox pops up (because it's a wrong input in th TextBox) so it becomes a indefinite loop, If the user click through mouse, this bug ins not there. So I want to handle it in my way. I want the main window hittestVisibility = False so that it does not gets hit

Comment: I am sorry but what you just described is not possible. You hit enter and MessageBox gets closed. The event is not going back to MainWindow since MessageBox has is its own dialog/window with its own VisualTree. Not sure if even MessageBoxes even have a visual tree since MessageBoxes existed for ages (even in WinForms) and their look hasnt changed a bit. :) hehe. However, MessageBoxes are its own unit. If by hitting enter or clicking on OK in MessagesBox every event will sink through then you would also execute click on underlaying Button or any control. And thats not the case.

Comment: This is hapenning, that's why I am worried. I know as soon as I hit Enter Key messagebox disappears but then again the textBox takes the Enter key and again MesageBox comes up. One thing I want to point out that I am displaying this MessageBox from ViewModel.

Comment: Where do you call your MessageBox from? Give us more code-

Comment: Added the code for better understanding ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39982/discussion-between-debhere-and-dev-hedgehog)

Comment: I just saw your comment about chat room :)